# Converting a char in a string array to float

Tags: c++, string, casting, char

I'm working on a project which takes a string input from the user of coordinates.
example of input:

```
"Polygons = [(1, 1), (4, 1), (4, 5), (3,5), (1, 5); (5,3), (3, 4), (6, 4), (6, 12), (3, 12)]"
```

One of the functions that I am making is checking the minimum/maximum X, which is clearly any number after a "(", however the problem that's bugging me is converting what's after the ( into a float to use it in calculations and number comparisons.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "string"
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <cstdlib>
    using namespace std;
    //Using a constant string for testing
    string Polygon_Input = "Polygons = [(1, 1), (4, 1), (4, 5), (3,5), (1, 5); (5,3), (3, 4), (6, 4), (6, 12), (3, 12)]"; 
    string Operation;
    float Min_X = 9999;
    int main()
    {

        getline(cin, Operation);

        if (Operation == "Minimum_X")
        {
            for (int i; i <= Polygon_Input.length(); i++)
            {
                if (Polygon_Input[i] == '(')
                {

                   float X = Polygon_Input[i + 1];
                   if (X < Min_X)
                   {
                       Min_X = X;
                   }

                }

            }
            cout << Min_X;
        }
```

That's not working, it always prints out 49 as Min_X

I also tried the same code with one modification, but still doesn't work.

```
    if (Polygon_Input[i] == '(')
    {

        string X_As_String = Polygon_Input.substr(i + 1, i + 1);
        float X = atof(X_As_String.c_str());
       if (X < Min_X)
       {
           Min_X = X;
       }
```

Comment: Since all `x`es are bigger than `0` and you initialize `Min_x` to 0, your `X < Min_X` will never be true.

Comment: Changed the initialization value, still doesn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, there are several problems in your code.

> float Min_X = 9999;

The minimum value **must** be in the list. Initialize the first element as the minimum value and compare it with the rest.

> if (X < Min_X)

The value X is `int` whereas `Min_X` is float. Don't compare int with float. Declare both as `float` and then cast if you would like an integer number.

> for (int i=0; i <= Polygon_Input.length(); i++)

Pay attention to `<=`. It should be `<`.

Now the solution for your problem is

```
//#include <limits> // no need for this 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
//Using a constant string for testing
string Polygon_Input = "Polygons = [(1, 1), (4, 1), (4, 5), (3,5), (1, 5); (5,3), (3, 4), (6, 4), (6, 12), (3, 12)]"; 
string Operation("Minimum_X");
//float Min_X = 9999; ?????? Why
float Min_X;
bool flag(true);

int main()
{
  //getline(cin, Operation); // commented out for test

  if (Operation == "Minimum_X")
  {
      for (int i=0; i < Polygon_Input.size(); i++)
      {
          if ( Polygon_Input[i] == '(' )
          {
             // extract X values (i.e. the first co-ordinate of a point )
             std::string temp = Polygon_Input.substr(i+1, Polygon_Input.find_first_of(",",i)-i-1 );
             // convert strig to float 
             float X = std::stof(temp); 

             // store first element and compare it with the rest
             if(flag){
                 Min_X = X;
                 flag=false;
             }

             // int X = Polygon_Input[i + 1] - '0'; ????? What is this?
             if (X < Min_X)
             {
                 Min_X = X;
             }

          }

      }
      cout <<  Min_X << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output is

`1`

which the minimum X value in the list. This code handles float values as well (i.e. (3.45, 4)). Try different values for checking.

Comment: If you have initialized `Min_X` properly then `Min_X` value need not be initialized with a value from the list.

Comment: Also If you have initialized Min_X properly, `flag` variable is unnecessary. And for the `What is this?` part of your comment in code, OP was of intention to solve the issue and making the code work for multiple digits number was a secondary thing which I suggested. It was not a part of the question. Also the same was discussed and clarified by the OP in comments on my answer.

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni, "If you have initialized `Min_X` properly" you can't initialize it since user needs to enter the values at the running time. There are several methods for avoiding `flag` but using `flag` avoids adding more codes.

Comment: You are the best of the best!, really thank you, you solved it <3

Comment: Can I ask you a question, why didn't we use find instead of find_first_of?

Comment: Another question :D, I've tried to store the values of X that I get in an array, however it doesn't work(No errors).. trying to collect the values of X in an array

Comment: Also can you please explain the parameters of find_first_of?, thank you.

Comment: @AliAmaim, take a look at [std::string::find_first_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/). For storing values, you better utilize `std::vector<float>` and use `.push_back()`.